# display values in List string into dataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a List of string and I need display the values of this list in a DataGrid. I have this:

```
public void DisplaySetInformation2(List<string> setList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < setList.Count; i++)
    {
        _dataGridSection.ItemsSource = setList[i].ToString();
    }
}
```

but it does not work.

What can I do?

Comment: You should have tagged it under Silverlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add every item. Just set the list as datasource.

```
_dataGridSection.ItemsSource = setList;
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work? this will only display string length in `datagrid` column.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do something like this..

create a class which will contain string

```
 public class StringValue
        {
            public StringValue(string value)
                {
                stringValue = value;
                }

             public string stringValue {get; set;}
        }
```

create a `List<StringValue> stringValues = new List<StringValue>(){new StringValue("Hello"), new StringValue("World")};`

then 
`dataGrid.ItemsSource = stringValues;`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a DataGridView instead.  That will probably be easier to work with.